# Tailwind responsive flexbox property is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend, tailwind-css

By default, ul has a **justify-start** flexbox property. When applying a responsive design for a **small** screen: it will be **justify-center**, for the **medium** screen: **justify-around** and for the **large** screen: **justify-evenly**.
However, for all screen sizes, it only showing justify-evenly property, it overrides all the other justify-property.
How is it possible to apply different justify-property for the different screens?

```
         <nav className='py-8'>
          <ul className='flex flex-row justify-start bg-red-400 sm:flex-row-reverse justify-center md:flex-row justify-around lg:flex-row-reverse justify-evenly'>
            <Link href='#'>
              <a className='p-2 text-2xl font-bold transition duration-500 hover:bg-indigo-300'> Beginnings</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href='#'>
              <a className='p-2 text-2xl font-bold hover:bg-indigo-300'> Now</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href='#'>
              <a className='p-2 text-2xl font-bold hover:bg-indigo-300'> Tech</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href='#'>
              <a className='p-2 text-2xl font-bold hover:bg-indigo-300'> Talks</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href='#'>
              <a className='p-2 text-2xl font-bold hover:bg-indigo-300'> Connect</a>
            </Link>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the breakpoint prefixes to each `justify-*` class, or else it gets applied to all breakpoints. Being that `justify-evenly` is last it's the one that ends up being applied.

```
<ul className='flex flex-row justify-start bg-red-400 sm:flex-row-reverse sm:justify-center md:flex-row md:justify-around lg:flex-row-reverse lg:justify-evenly'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've added generic `justify-around` and `justify-evenly` classes instead of screen-size prefixed `md:justify-around` and `lg:justify-evenly`. In Tailwind, un-prefixed classes apply to all screen-sizes. Prefixed classes apply to all screen-sizes greater or equal to the given prefix.

```html
<ul className='flex flex-row justify-start bg-red-400 sm:flex-row-reverse justify-center md:flex-row md:justify-around lg:flex-row-reverse lg:justify-evenly'>
```